# Autoclose colorbox vimeo iframe video when finnished?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, vimeo

I'm using colorbox to display an vimeo clip on pageload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='bvssp-vimeo.js'></script>
</head>

<a style="display:none;" class="vimeo" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67189599?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0&amp;autoplay=1">hidden</a>

</body>
</html>
```

bvssp-vimeo.js looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:830, innerHeight:466, open: true});
});
```

This will popup an iframe playing a vimeo clip. Everything works fine. What I do wonder if there is a way to autoclose the iframe when the vimeo-clip is finnished. Is this really possible? What is the best way to determinate when the vimeoclip is finnished and automatically close the iframe?

UPDATE:
I updated the bvssp-vimeo.js with the following code to make it work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:830, innerHeight:466, open: true});

});

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.colorbox.close();
}, 20000);
```

==========================
UPDATE 2:

I have found out thet the solution above works but it's not ideal because let's say the video is 1min long and you set the time to 1 min.. If you're on a slow connection and the video starts to buffer it will stop playing too quickly.

One solution is to look at the vimeo Froogaloop API and I really need help here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />



    <!-- Inkludera javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="froogaloop.js"></script>

<!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='bvssp-vimeo.js'></script> -->

</head>
<body>



        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($blaha) {

                $blaha(".cboxIframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:830, innerHeight:466, open: true});


            // Enable the API on each Vimeo video
            jQuery('iframe.cboxIframe').each(function(){

                Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
            });

            function ready(playerID){

                // Add event listerns
                Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('play', play(playerID));
                Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('seek', seek);
                Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('finish', finish);

                // Fire an API method
                Froogaloop(playerID).api('play');

            }
            function play(playerID){
                alert(playerID + " is playing!!!");
            }
            function seek() {
                alert('Seeking');
            }
            function finish() {
                alert('Finnished');
                $blaha.colorbox.close();
            }

        });

        </script>

<a style="display:none;" class="cboxIframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&player_id=player2">dd</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Vimeo API hase a solution for stoping videos when it ends but I'm unable to make this work with colorbox.

The code outputed by colorbox seems all ok and if i copy it from the Firefox developer webconsole and paste it directly in the document everything works. This is strange...

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you out.

Find the length of the video file convert it, into milliseconds, so as to pass here to setTimeout.

```
setTimeout("closeIframe()",<length of vidofile in milliseconds>);
```

And with this function this should work.

```
function check_if_open() {
    var t=setTimeout("closeIframe()",30000);
    }



    function closeIframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('someid');
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    }

<iframe id="someid" src="http://www.somethg.com" width="700" height="700"   onload="check_if_open()">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Hello @SAM. THis issue is not solved. Well your suggestion works but it's ot ideal because for example the video is 1min long and you set the time to be 1 minute and you're on a slow connection and maybe the video starts to buffer, the video will stop playing to quickly...

I wil update my question with new code shortly...

Oh thank you for the help so far...

Answer (score 0):

read this documentation about the vimeo api http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

in my case the popup colorbox call a page with the video with this code in this page it's work.

```
<script>
var f = $('iframe'),
    url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0],
    status = $('.status');

// Listen for messages from the player
if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
}

// Handle messages received from the player
function onMessageReceived(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    switch (data.event) {
        case 'ready':
            onReady();
            break;

        case 'finish':
            onFinish();
            break;
    }
}

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').on('click', function() {
    post($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

// Helper function for sending a message to the player
function post(action, value) {
    var data = { method: action };

    if (value) {
        data.value = value;
    }

    f[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
}


function onReady() {
   post('addEventListener', 'finish');
}


function onFinish() {
window.parent.$.colorbox.close();
}

</script>
```